# Converting Firebase value(Int) to String leads to error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get some values from my JSON tree which is in Firebase however I am getting error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x1a7c497f0) to
>   'NSString' (0x1a7c55398).

The way I set the value is this:

```
let values = ["username": username, "email": email, "reputation": reputation] as [String : Any]
```

I get value like this:

```
self.databaseRef.child("users").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

            //store the logged in users details into the variable

            print(self.loggedInUser)
            let snapshot = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
            self.usernameLabel.text = snapshot["username"] as! String
            self.reputationLabel.text = snapshot["reputation"] as! String//This is giving me error
})
```

What I am doing wrong? What is causing this? In Swift 2 it worked but not in Swift 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're retrieving from firebase is probably of type double. try using this :

```
self.reputationLabel.text = "\(snapshot["reputation"])"
```

EDIT:

if this is giving you nil, try to use a conditional unwrap :

```
if let reputation = snapshot["reputation"] {
    self.reputationLabel.text = "\(reputation)"
} else {
    print("reputation is nil")
}
```

if your data is nil then check your data name in firebase, and your objects in the db